# Using Knockout Validation with knockout.utils.extend

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, prototype, knockout-validation

How can I use ko.validation with ko.utils extend?

This is what ive tried and I think as im fairly new to JS I might be making a fundamental error (errors im getting are in comments):

```
var Customer = function (data) {
    var cus = this;
    cus.FirstName = ko.observable();
    cus.LastName = ko.observable();
    cus.Email = ko.observable();//.extend({ required: true, email: true });
    // above line causes 'Uncaught TypeError: observable.extend is not a function'

    //extenders
    this.cleanData = data;// copy of original Customer
    this.initData(data);//call your prototype init function 

};

// Extend the Customer object to init with data & also so we can revert back to original if user cancel's 
ko.utils.extend(Customer.prototype, {
    initData: function (data) {
        this.FirstName(data.FirstName);
        this.LastName(data.LastName);
        this.Email(data.Email).extend({ required: true, email: true });
        // above line causes 'this.Email(...).extend is not a function'
    },
    revert: function () {
        this.initData(this.cleanData);
    }
});
```

This code below works fine if I remove the ko.utils.extend (loosing init/revert in the process) in the Customer object:

```
    var Customer = function (data) {
    var cus = this;
    cus.FirstName = ko.observable(data.FirstName);
    cus.LastName = ko.observable(data.LastName);
    this.Email(data.Email).extend({ required: true, email: true });// works fine - but weve lost 'ko.utils.extend' functionality
};
```

Unfortunately as I say im loosing the init & revert which I need.

So what im asking is am I making a daft mistake here and can someone please explain how this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault is just in your initData method. This line is OK:

```
cus.Email = ko.observable();//.extend({ required: true, email: true });
```

It is this bit that doesn't work:

```
this.Email(data.Email).extend({ required: true, email: true });
```

You can use extend via the `ko.observable` function but you cannot then use .extend on the result of setting the observable. To fix your code, do:

```
// Set it
this.Email(data.Email);
// Then extend it
this.Email.extend({ required: true, email: true });
```

Here's a fiddle to show you:

http://jsfiddle.net/2wLL3exc/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, im still getting the error but I think its related to ko.validation, when I set parseInputAttributes: false the error stops (but so does the validation).

Comment: Any chance you can work this into your question or reproduce it in a fiddle? It is quite hard to help further without seeing more of your problem.

Comment: You answered the question si, many thanks, my app has other issues with validation (forms in templates wont validate) so im currently updating my app to use ko.bindinghandlers for the modals (i was using knockstrap with templates) trying to be clever has cost me. BTW small world im in Retford not too far from sheff. Thanks again